# Do I have to initilize a variable in the same scope I declare it in Java?

Tags: java

I came across this very simple code, and it seems to me that we have to initialize a variable in the same scope we declare it, if so I am confused to as to why. Here is an example:

```
class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int x; // if initialize x to anything everything works fine

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            x = 3;
            System.out.println("in loop : " + x);
        }

        System.out.println("out of loop " + x); // expect x = 3 here, but get an error
    }
}
```

The above code produces this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The local variable x may not have been initialized
```

I am confused as to why this is happening. I expected `int x` to tell Java compiler that I will create a `int` variable `x` in the scope that declared `x`, then I initialized `x` to the value of 3 in the for loop. What causes the error? What am I missing?

As a side note, very similar code works as I expected in C++

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace::std;

int main()
{
    int x;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        x = 3;
        cout<<"in loop : "<<x<<endl;
    }

    cout<<"out of loop : "<<x<<endl; //expect x = 3 here

    return 0;
}
```

I am using eclipse for java and Code::Blocks for C++.

Comment: in C++, x is initialized to garbage.  Java does you the favor of not letting that happen.

Comment: @DWright +1 `-Wall` may point this out, not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know *for sure* you're going to enter the loop. So `x` may never get initialized.

Consider:

```
class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int x;                        // x has no value

        for (int i = 0; i < 0; i++)   // Bogus bounds -> never enters loop.
        {
            x = 3;                    // Never happens
            System.out.println("in loop : " + x);
        }

        System.out.println("out of loop " + x); // x has no value here!!
    }
}
```

Go ahead and initialize `x` to *something*. If *you* are certain the loop will be entered, and a value assigned, then don't worry what the initialization value is.  Otherwise, you now see why that initialization is required.

Comment: I like the never entering for loop example. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

As per [JLS 16 (Definite Assignment)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html#jls-16.2.4)

> For every access of a local variable or blank final field x, x must be definitely assigned before the access, or a compile-time error occurs.

In this case compiler is not sure about for loop, which  is why you seeing compile time error.